# Binding visibility to arrayController selection

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I have a `NSTableView` bound to a `NSArrayController`.

I have two buttons below the table that must be enabled only if there is an element selected on the table.

I select the buttons and bind `Availability` `Enabled` to `Table1 Controller`, `selectedObjects` but I get this error

> Cocoa Bindings: Cannot create BOOL from object <_NSCachedIndexSet: 0x60000023b4e0>(no indexes) of class _NSCachedIndexSet

What is obvious, because `selectedObjects` is an `NSIndexSet` and the property is expecting a `Bool`.

In fact the buttons should be enabled if `selectedObjects` is not nil and disabled if that property is nil.

How do I do that? I mean, create a bool out of an array property so I can bind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set *Controller Key* to `selectedObjects` and *Model Key path* to [`@count`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html)

Comment: BRILLIANT! What other key paths I can use? Where do I learn about them?

Comment: Please read the linked article or search for *KVC collection operators*